# Not getting the expected results at pointer increment

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Pointer increment not giving the right value, it points to indeterminate address.

Want to know why `*p++= <value>` not pointing to the value I want instead it points to something else

**My code:**

```
void run_exe() {
    int i;
    uint8_t buf[20] = {"0"};
    uint8_t *p = NULL;
    uint8_t tx_buf[4] = {1,1,1,1};

    p = buf;
    *p++ = 0x14;        
    *p++ = 0x20;        
    *p++ = 0x30;        
    *p++ = 0x40;        
    *p++ = 0x50;        
    *p++ = 0x60;        
    memcpy( p+6, tx_buf, sizeof(tx_buf));
   // ARRAY_SIZE: is the macro just my array length.

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(buf); i++) {
        printf("%d ", *(p+i));
    }

}
```

I'm printing the decimal value of HEX but at least I'm expecting the correct value but I get indeterminate value.

I'm expecting the output like this.

```
14 20 30 40 50 60 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

**Output:**

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 255 127 0 0 0
```

Comment: After you do `p++` six times, where does `p` point?

Comment: @SouravGhosh, I didn't understand your comment. You mean to say, I need allocated memory to *p?

Comment: In fact, there's no need for `p` *at all* in the code you show. You can just use `buf` with normal array indexing (*and* pointer arithmetic if that's what you want).

Comment: @DanglingPointer please ignore, I misread the code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OP specifically wants `p` to point to `buf` and print it using `p`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for pointing out,  p points to buf. In that case just printing the buf is more than enough. It's silly mistake.

Comment: @DanglingPointer Not after your incrementing of `p`. Then it points to `buf[6]`, which is your problem. When you do e.g. `*p++ = 0x14;` it's the same as doing `*p = 0x14; p = p + 1;`.

Comment: You are going out of array bounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an auxiliary pointer,

```
uint8_t *ptr;

p = buf;
ptr = p;

*p++ = 0x14;
```

and so on, because the `++` will modify the pointer's value.

Then,

```
for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(buf); i++) {
    printf("%d ", ptr[i]);
}
```

The `++` post-increment or pre-increment operator, makes the pointer `p` point to `p + 1` after the expression is evaluated, so your `p` is *NOT* pointing to `buf` when you attempt to print it.

---

**EDIT**: Of course you can just do this too,

```
for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(buf); i++) {
    printf("%d ", buf[i]);
}
```

but I think the original answer explains the reason which is the important thing.

---

**EXTRA**: Also, I am 99.9% sure that this is wrong

```
uint8_t buf[20] = {"0"};
```

you meant,

```
uint8_t buf[20] = {0};
```

your compiler might be showing you a warning for this initialization which is faulty, because `"0"` has pointer type and even though it's convertible to a integer type, it mostly certainly doesn't fit a `uint8_t` so you have a overflow issue there.

Comment: Or just use `buf` straight of?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Of course. I can see that now, but when I decided to answer I didn't know where `p` came from. While writing it ... well I decided to leave it as it was.

Comment: yes I mean initializing the array element with 0. that is wrong not string literal thing, don't know why the compiler didn't complain about that.

Comment: `"0"` has array type. It probably compiles because `uint8_t` is normally a typedef for `unsigned char`, an array of which can be initialized from a string literal